# Mutate a value stored in an enum in a Vec

Tags: rust

The following code fails to compile with the error below:

```
enum Test {
    C(i32),
}

fn main() {
    let mut v = Vec::new();

    v.push(Test::C(0));

    if let Some(Test::C(ref mut c)) = v.last_mut() {
        *c = *c + 1;
    }
}
```

> ```
> error[E0308]: mismatched types
>   --> src/main.rs:10:17
>    |
> 10 |     if let Some(Test::C(ref mut c)) = v.last_mut() {
>    |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected &mut Test, found enum `Test`
>    |
>    = note: expected type `&mut Test`
>               found type `Test`
> ```

`last_mut()` returns a mutable reference, and I'm taking the `i32` as a mutable reference. I've tried making the mutability even more clear as follows, but I get the same compiler error.

```
if let Some(ref mut e) = v.last_mut() {
    if let Test::C(ref mut c) = e {
        *c = *c + 1;
    }
}
```

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to match exactly what the error message says. It expects a `&mut Test`, so you should match on that:

```
if let Some(&mut Test::C(ref mut c)) = v.last_mut() {
    //     ^^^^^^
    *c = *c + 1;
}
```

Here [it is running in the playground](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=b7a5250b40e1a70c071f485ebb63c3ef&version=stable).

As of [Rust 1.26](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-1260-2018-05-10), your original code works as-is and the explicit `ref` and `ref mut` keywords are no longer required:

```
if let Some(Test::C(c)) = v.last_mut() {
    *c = *c + 1;
}
```

Comment: Grr, I can't believe I missed that. Why is it that the second form with the 2 if statements doesn't work?

Comment: @Tim: Because it has the same problem.  In the second example, `e` is of type `&mut &mut Test`.  The issue is that you're ignoring the borrows when writing the patterns; you can't do that.

Comment: Normally, you'd write `if let Some(Test::C(ref mut c)) = *v.last_mut() {`. I think this is also covered by [RFC 2005](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2005-match-ergonomics.md), which will allow `if let Some(Test::C(ref mut c)) = v.last_mut() {` to work.

Comment: Errr. disregard my point about the version with `*v.last_mut()`, not sure what I was thinking ^_^. The point about RFC 2005 stands (I hope).